# opendj (2.6), how to MANUALLY unlock a user who has locked his account due to failed logins

Tags: ldap, opendj

I need to implement a lock and unlock mechanism in opendj 2.6 based on a fixed failed login attempt. I've already seen that there are two methods (https://backstage.forgerock.com/docs/opendj/2.6/admin-guide/#chap-account-lockout). a manual method (which I don't care about at all because I've already done some testing and found that it only allows manual locking and unlocking) and the second one which was perfect for me because, by modifying the password policy, it allows me to set a fixed number of failed attempts and set a lockout time out.

my goal: I need to find a way to unlock this type of locked users without spending the entire lockout time.

my problem: i have already read the documentation and apparently resetting the user's password is the only way.

ps: I also noticed that, when a user is locked, some attributes are added to his entry, such as: pwdAccountLockedTime and I thought I could delete this attribute manually, but that field was a non-editable field (and also I had no certainty that it would work).

Do you have any suggestions? Or is it simply not allowed?

Answer (score 0):

As you have already identified, the proper way to unlock an account after N consecutive failures is to reset the password. If a user is entering  a wrong password 5 times, do you think he will know the correct one the 6th time ?
Otherwise, OpenDJ has a tool called manage-account, where specific operations are possible. This should only be used by an admin with care.
I believe not all operations are documented, but you may read the code to understand them all.

Comment: I absolutely agree with you but i'm studying to see if it's possible or not (because we're talking about a solution for corporate users who don't have time, and especially desire, to type correctly... so they probably need 2/3 attempts at least to get access, even knowing the password). I've already seen the manage-account tool but apparently the lockdown method between these two solutions (manual lockdown and N time lockdown) are different and I can't use the first one to unlock a user who has been locked with the second one. thanks for the answer and the suggestion about code review.

Comment: Please, look at all hides commands of manage-account (or read ForgeRock documentation. About this command). You will find a solution to unlock users who have locked themselves with bad passwords. Note that offering users a way to unlock themselves without properly authenticating, is also allowing a hacker to continue to crack the password ! The proper protection is to lock the account for a period of time to slow attacks, or force a reset.